# How does "missing \begin{document}" work?

Tags: errors, titles, documentclass-writing

I would like to know how does LaTeX invoke the error `Missing \begin{document}`. I would like to reproduce it in the sense of the following MWE (it will become a part of my own document class):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{My titlE} % <-- these are fine
\author{tohecz}
\def\A{\mathbf{A}}

Hello % <-- should invoke error "Text before `\maketitle` command"
% the error should be invoked even when `\maketitle` is missing at all

\maketitle

World % <-- this is fine

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LaTeX uses the `\everypar` token register to set up the error. If you try `\showthe\everypar` before `\begin{document}` you will see

```
> \@nodocument .
l.3 \showthe\everypar
```

The internal command `\@nodocument` expands to give the error. This works as TeX inserts `\everypar` each time it starts a paragraph, and that happens when it encounters horizontal mode material while in vertical mode. TeX starts off in vertical mode, and the first letter or similar causes a switch to horizontal mode, inserts `\everypar` and thus here fires the error.

Part of the `\document` macro removes `\@nodocument` from `\everypar`. So you want to add something to it, and remove or disable it again as part of `\maketitle`. You also need to activate that in the right place, at the end of `\document`. Something like

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\document}{\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\my@title@check}}        
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\global\let\my@title@check\relax}
\newcommand*{\my@title@check}{\PackageError{MyPkg}{Missing \protect\maketitle}\@ehc}
\makeatother
```

Rather than remove the check from `\everypar`, I've taken the route of simply converting it to a no-op once `\maketitle` has been used. You could also use a flag, for example if you have further tests to do. (Removing from the toks would require a bit of care for the general case, so I'm avoiding the issue.)

Comment: Ok, so `\everypar` is the key! I was thinking about `\EveryShipout` that would invoke the error at the end of the first page, but I was sure LaTeX does not use anything like that.

Comment: Just please, what does `\@ehc` do? Does it come from "end document hook"?

Comment: @tohecz `\@ehc` is a generic error handler command. I've used `\PackageError`, which needs two arguments, the first 'error text' and the second 'more error text'. In common with a lot of the LaTeX kernel errors, I've decided I'm not going to write 'more error text' but just use `\@ehc` to give something generic.